# Which LEGO sets do these pieces belong to? Star Wars? White, grey, yellow

Tags: set-identification

I got these LEGO sets from a consignment sale.  They were all in a gallon-sized Ziploc bag.  Any thoughts on which sets they came from? The first bag is open and I've been assuming that the loose pieces came from inside it, but I suppose that could be incorrect.  The other two bags are still sealed.

The loose pieces look similar to some of the pieces from the LEGO Star Wars Anakin's Jedi Interceptor 75281 LEGO set.

[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/bsB4TUu5z5FuvSkU9]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

[image: image 5]

[image: image 6]

Answer (score 5):

According to BrickLink:

Bag 2 has at least 2 white [15625](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15625#T=C) (Slope, Curved 5 x 8 x 2/3 with Four Studs). Only two sets have at least 2, and only 1 also has a yellow Technic coat hanger [99773](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99773) (Technic, Liftarm, Modified Triangle Thin, Type II) - [75170](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75170-1) (The Phantom)

[image: 75170]

The big rounded windscreen looks like [50986pb001](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50986pb001&in=S) (Windscreen 10 x 6 x 3 Bubble Canopy Double Tapered with Dark Bluish Gray Jedi Starfighter Pattern) which was in 3 sets. Only 1 also has a black [47407](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=47407&colorID=11&in=A) (Wedge, Plate 4 x 6) - [7661](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7661-1) (Jedi Starfighter with Hyperdrive Booster Ring)

[image: 7661]

Comment: Bag 3 is also from 75170, because you can see the torso of Admiral Thrawn in the bottom left corner. The seal code on the bag corresponds with the lifespan of this set as well - R7 means 2017. The good news is that Admiral Thrawn is exclusive to this set and hence expensive to obtain ($60+ for a new one on Bricklink).

Comment: Looking at all pictures, I think you have part of bag 1 and all of bag 2 and 3 of set 75170, plus some random parts. In the loose part picture you can see Kanan Jarrus as well, another expensive minifigure at $20+ on Bricklink. This figure also belongs to 75170. The red motorcycle fairing (18895) can be from a number of other sets, so these are truly random parts thrown together.

Comment: The 8x8 piece with a sticky-outy bit is 15624  Brick, Modified 8 x 8 x 2/3 with 1 x 4 Indentations and 1 x 4 Plate <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=15624&colorID=85&in=A> - in 13 sets in DkBley.